# CSS selector: first child of parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select the first element of a parent matching a specific type; the css equivalent of `$(parent).children()[0]`. For example, `h1` tags that are the first child of a parent:

```
<div>
  <h1 id="foo"></h1>     // match
  <div></div>            // not match
  …
</div>
<section>
  <h1 id="bar"></h1>    // match
  <div></div>           // not match
  …
</section>
<div>
  <div id="baz"></div> // not match
  <h1 id="qux"></h1>   // not match
  …
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/bvZAJ/)**

**EDIT** I am aware that there is no 'parent' selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest, if you want to match the *first* `h1` of a parent element (in compliant browsers) using `:first-of-type`:

```
h1:first-of-type {
    /* CSS to style the first h1 of its parent element */
}
```

If, however, you want to style a `h1` element only if it's the first child of its parent:

```
h1:first-child {
    /* CSS to style the h1 only if it's the first-child of its parent element */
}
```

Comment: oh wow. really i had quite the daft moment. of course :first-child, duh. Thanks ^^,